# Set secure param in Google Analytics Tracking Code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, https, google-analytics

I'm trying to set **secure=true** in Google Analytics cookies: utma, utmb, utmc, utmz, utmv y utmx like I did in Rails app with:

cookies[:web] = {:value => 'XXXXXXXX', **:secure => true** }

Should I change the next Google Analytics Tracking Code? Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];   s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the "secure" flag? What are you making secure?

Answer (score 1):

No.In my opinion,you needn't to change the Google Analytics Tracking Code.